# Saved search report netsuite

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

[image]

I want create saved search report in netsuite Column 1, column2, column 3.
Need to month wise Like Jan-24 then below line column 1... column 3 data in row as shown in image.
How I can do that using Saved search in netsuite report as shown in image?

[image]